# ¿Cómo usar una función llamada en otro admin?

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, django-admin

Tengo 2 admin/ en una tengo esta función:

```
def show_data_user(self, obj):
    if obj.is_individual():
        return self.show_owner(obj)

    obj = obj.get_real_instance()
    return mark_safe('<br>'.join(
        filter(
           None, [
            self.show_nombre(obj),
            self.show_apellido(obj),
            self.show_business(obj),
        ]
    )
)
)
```

Y en el segundo *admin* quiero llamar la función que tengo en el primero "*show_data_user*", pero me sale este error:

> show_nombre() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'

Yo lo he llamado de esta forma (sin mucho éxito):

```
def show_trabajador(self, obj):
    from trabajadorData.admin import Titular
    if obj.titular and isinstance(obj.titular, Trabajador):
        return Titular.show_data_user(
            Titular.show_nombre(obj),
            Titular.show_apellido(obj),
            Titular.show_business(obj)
        )
```

¿Cómo debería llamarlo? y en el caso de que en esa función solo quisiera que me apareciera el valor de *show_nombre* y *show_apellido*.

Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.